# Firing radio buttins shows and hides textbox in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Very simple but no idea why it doesn't fire.
I want a text box to open up when the user clicks on "yes" and for it to hide when the user clicks on "no" and when nothing is selected.
I looked it up and I found some code that should be working but it isn't.

This is my HTML:

```
     <form name="form2" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="post">
        <fieldset id= "fieldset2">
        <legend>Step 2</legend>
            Would you like your company name on your badges?<br>
            <input type="radio" id="companyYes" name="company">Yes<input type="radio" id="companyNo" name="company">No<br>
            <input type="text" id="companyText">
        <br>
        <div id="company"></div>
        Will anyone in your group require special accommodations?<br>
       (if yes) Please explain below:<br>
        <input type="radio" name="special" id="specialYes" value="Yes">Yes<input type="radio" id="specialNo" name="special" value="No">No<br>
        <input type="text" id="specialText">
            <img id="check" src="check.png">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

This is my JS:

```
$("#companyYes").on("click", function() {
    $("#companyText").show();
});
$("#companyNo").on("click", function() {
    $("#companyText").hide();    
});
$("#specialYes").on("click", function() {
    $("#specialText").show();
});
$("#specialNo").on("click", function() {
    $("#specialText").hide();
});
$(Document).on("click",function(){

}
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#check").hide();
    $("#specialText").hide();
    $("#companyText").hide();
});
```

Comment: put all js code into document ready

Comment: You should start your app with your elements hidden. You could achieve this adding a class to those elements with `display:none;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

You are missing a `);` in

```
$(Document).on("click",function(){

}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3063rqtb/8/):

**Side Note:**

1. Better to put the click events inside `document.ready()` too
2. Instead of hiding the objects at page load with jQuery use pure css (`display: none;`) so they will not flicker when the page first loads

Comment: Thank you so much it seems to work in JSFiddle, but not on my brackets, I don't understand why...

Comment: Put the click events inside the `document.ready();` too. See this updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3063rqtb/8/)

Comment: That completely fixed it, thank you so much. I learn more every day, hopefully fast enough!